# not get image path in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have tried different syntax as belows.

1. `"<img src='../Images/Live news/Actions-arrow-right-icon.png'  />" ;`
2. `<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Images/Live news/Actions-arrow-right-icon.png") %>"`

I want to add image through controller not view so is these syntex are correct?

This is my full code

```
 dt = Users.Get_Livenews(0, true, "GActive");
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
 { 
  objExercise = new HomeModel();
  objExercise.livenews = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["livenews_headline"].ToString()) + "<img src='../Images/Live news/Actions-arrow-right-icon.png' />" ; 
  Horizontal.Add(objExercise); 
 }
```

Comment: not able to understand the question???

Comment: I want to add image threw controller so i have tried the code above

Comment: dt = Users.Get_Livenews(0, true, "GActive");
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                objExercise = new HomeModel();
                objExercise.livenews = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["livenews_headline"].ToString()) + **"<img src='../Images/Live news/Actions-arrow-right-icon.png'**  />" ;
                 Horizontal.Add(objExercise);
            }

Comment: This is my full code

Comment: plz post that thing in your question..

Comment: @Exception can you tell me whats wrong in it??

Comment: Sorry but i m not getting you what you are trying to do...

Comment: Just adding image through which I have coded in controller

Comment: why are you giving static image paths in controller ???

Comment: becose i want to add it after every livenews..

Comment: what is Horizontal..it's a list???

Comment: Adding html mark-up in your controller is a very bad idea. Why are you not wanting to just add it in the View?

Comment: ok i solve it add it in the View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the list of image paths from controller and then iterate the this list at View level. Means dynamically create images for each image path you iterate.

If your view is strongly-typed and controller returns view with model or say list object then using for or foreach loop, you can prepare table or whatever you need.